How would a Garou missing an arm affect its stats?
This question is about 20th Anniversary edition if it helps.
Whether from losing it in battle, or a metis born with one arm - I was hoping to ask if there’s anything explicit anywhere on how this affects them stats-wise?
Whether there’s something written on it lowers an overall stat but rolls are normal, or if certain rolls are at a minus (overall or form dependent wise)?
If not, does anyone have any playtested experience about how they house-ruled this? For a PC or an NPC.

Missing limbs or sensory organs appear at multiple spots in the rules!
There are two places where missing or defective limbs show up in the rules.
Flaw
The One Arm Flaw for 3 points, as identified by CatLord.

One Arm (3 pt. Flaw) You were either born with only one arm or lost your arm through an injury of some sort. You suffer no secondary-hand penalty, since you have adapted to using your one hand for most activities. When you need to use two hands, however, you lose two dice from your dice pool. Your running speed in Hispo and Lupus form is 1/2 of normal. Metis characters may take this Flaw (for no freebie points) as their inherent deformity.1

Battle Scar
There's also the Battlescar of Maimed Limb,

Maimed Limb: One of your limbs has been mauled
to the point of uselessness. If you lost a leg, you move at
half speed in all forms. If you lost an arm, your Hispo and
Lupus speed is reduced to three-quarters. You are not able to
use the damaged limb for any purpose. 2

Difference
There is a substantive difference between the two: The One Arm-Flaw costs 2 dice on twohanded things, and reduces speed by 50%. The Maimed Limb Battlescar reduces speed by 25% for arms (and 50% for legs), but does not specify a penalty for twohanded things specifically. That is still faster than Lame, which is a reduction of speed by 75% and bans running:

Lame (3 pt. Flaw)
Either from birth, an accident, or a major battle scar,
your legs are damaged, which prevents you from running
or walking easily. You have a pronounced limp and may
need assistance from a cane or walking stick. Your walking
speed is one-quarter that of a normal human, and running
is impossible. Metis characters may take this Flaw (for no
freebie points) as their metis disfigurement.1

Is it special?
No. One Arm & Lame are not the same result as Maimed Limb rules-wise. Very similar to the damaged limb, is damage to the eyes, which exists both as a Battle Scar and a Flaw, and they are not identically worded or reference one another.

One Eye (2 pt. Flaw)
You lack depth perception and have limited vision,
due to the fact that you only have one eye. Your blind
side has no peripheral vision. The difficulties of all Perception
rolls involving eyesight are increased by two, and
when depth perception is involved (such as during ranged
combat), the difficulty is increased by an additional +1.3


Missing Eye: One of your eyes was gouged out and
hasn’t grown back. The difficulties on all rolls involving
depth perception or weapon firing (including using thrown
weapons) increase by three. Any Perception rolls based
on sight take a +2 difficulty penalty.2

The difference here? Missing eye increases the difficulty for depth perception by 3, One eye only by 1.

1 - W20, p.474.
2 - W20, p.260.
3 - W20, p.473.

Great additions. I started small and should have snagged the others.

@CatLord I just knew that missing organs (maimed limb) is a battlescar since 1st ed, but that the two are actively different in rules just popped up to me as I looked it up.

Thank you! This is very helpful. So it seems the maimed limbs/eye would be what is usually taken for a garou who perhaps recently lost it in battle, while one limb/eye more for either those garou who have lost it for a while and adapted or born without?

@anon pretty much. The Battlescar comes with some renown to help over the downside of it.

There's a flaw in W20, p474 in my book

One Arm (3 pt. Flaw)
You were either born with only one arm or lost
your arm through an injury of some sort. You suffer no
secondary-hand penalty, since you have adapted to using
your one hand for most activities. When you need to use
two hands, however, you lose two dice from your dice
pool. Your running speed in Hispo and Lupus form is 1/2
of normal. Metis characters may take this Flaw (for no
freebie points) as their inherent deformity.


Brilliant, thank you! That’s very helpful. For perspective: would  an example of something “needing two hands” that would cause that dice loss be like attacking with claws? Or is that under the adapted to criteria?

@anon I think it would be for things like firing a rifle, swinging two-handed sword, or rapidly typing on a keyboard.
